# 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 43: ordinal not in range(128) Python

Tags: python, codificación

Lo que pasa es que hice un programa que cuenta palabras en archivos txt en python, lo probe para algunos archivos en ingles pero cuando los archivos tienen caracteres como - ----- o ñ aparece
**Error**:

> 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 43: ordinal not in
>   range(128)

¿Alguien sabe cual podría ser el problema?
Gracias de antemano.   :)

**Código**

```py
archivo = input("Ingresa el nombre del archivo\n")
ahandle = open(archivo)
counts = dict()
for line in ahandle:
  words = line.split()
for word in words:
  counts[word] = counts.get(word, 0) + 1
bigcount = None
bigword = None
for word, count in counts.items():
  if bigcount is None or count > bigcount:
  bigword = word
bigcount = count
print(bigword, bigcount)
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero, sería necesario saber qué versión de python usas (si la 2 o la 3). Por los paréntesis en el `print()` voy a suponer que usas la 3.

Lo segundo, sería necesario saber qué codificación tiene el fichero que estás leyendo. Si estás en Linux o un Mac moderno lo más probable es que sea utf-8, pero también podría ser otra. Si estás en Windows podría ser iso-8859-15 o utf-8 (a menos que lo hayas creado desde un editor de consola, pero eso voy a descartarlo por improbable).

Dado que el error te lo da cuando encuentra un byte que vale `0xc3`, lo más seguro es que se trate de utf-8 (pues ese es el prefijo que usa ante los caracteres acentuados o la eñe).

Lo que tienes que hacer es especificar qué codificación usa el fichero como parte de los parámetros de `open()`, así por ejemplo:

```py
ahandle = open(archivo, encoding="utf-8")
```

Si te sigue fallando será que la codificación es otra.

Comment: Ya con el encoding="utf-8" quedo, ya abre todos los archivos. muchas gracias :)